# Find range from the javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to find the range between lowest and higest value . So if I have following datasets

```
Australia : 454545,
India : 56655,
China: 8989898,
Usa: 545444
```

Here range will be (8989898-56666 = 8933243) which is the difference between the lowest and highest values. I managed to find that in the following way

```js
let marks ={Australia : 100,India : 89,China: 78,Usa: 45}
let max=0;
let min=9999;
for (let m in marks) {  
  let mark=marks[m];
  if(mark>max){
    max=mark;
  }
  if(mark<min){
    min=mark;
  }
  
}

console.log(max);
console.log(min);
console.log(max-min);
```

But my problem here is that i have specified minimum arbitrary number 9999 for comparison , it will work most of the case but it wont if the datasets are greater than 9999, so what is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to how `Math.min` operates, you can set the initial value to Infinity:

```js
console.log(Math.min());
```

```js
let marks = {
  Australia: 100,
  India: 89,
  China: 78,
  Usa: 45
}
let max = 0;
let min = Infinity;
for (let m in marks) {
  let mark = marks[m];
  if (mark > max) {
    max = mark;
  }
  if (mark < min) {
    min = mark;
  }

}

console.log(max);
console.log(min);
console.log(max - min);
```

Or you could just invoke `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```js
let marks ={Australia : 100,India : 89,China: 78,Usa: 45}
const vals = Object.values(marks);
console.log(
  Math.max(...vals) - Math.min(...vals)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let marks = { Australia : 100, India : 89, China: 78,Usa: 45 };

var min = Infinity, max = -Infinity, x;
for( x in marks) {
    if( marks[x] < min) min = marks[x];
    if( marks[x] > max) max = marks[x];
}


console.log(max);
console.log(min);
console.log(max - min);
```